# Xfce in Xubuntu 12.04 keymap sitching

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce

i want to setup keymap switching in Xubuntu following way:
- Left Winkey for toggling keymaps
- "Scroll lock" led for alternative keymap indication

As it goes, it not so easy to setup by means of default Xfce tools.

Answer (score 2):

Here is soultoion using tiny oldie tool: "xxkb"

`$ sudo apt-get install xxkb`

`$ cat > ~/.Xkbmap`

Here paste this code raplacing `ru` in `layout` setting with your locale code:

```
  -layout us,ru
  -variant ,winkeys
  -option grp:lwin_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

`$ cat > ~/.xxkbrc`

```
XXkb.image.path: /usr/share/xxkb
XXkb.group.base: 1
XXkb.group.alt: 2
XXkb.mainwindow.enable: no
XXkb.mainwindow.type: tray
XXkb.mainwindow.image.1: en15.xpm
XXkb.mainwindow.image.2: ru15.xpm
XXkb.mainwindow.image.3:
XXkb.mainwindow.image.4:
XXkb.mainwindow.appicon: yes
XXkb.mainwindow.geometry: 15x15+2+2
XXkb.mainwindow.in_tray: false
XXkb.button.enable: no
XXkb.app_list.wm_class_name.start_alt: skype
XXkb.controls.add_when_start: yes
XXkb.controls.add_when_create: yes
XXkb.controls.add_when_change: no
XXkb.controls.focusout: no
XXkb.mainwindow.label.enable: no
```